# Apple and shared_ptr

Tags: c++, macos, shared-ptr

I seem to be missing something here. I moved from `boost::shared_ptr` to `std::shared_ptr`. `shared_ptr` was part of TR1 back in the mid-2000s, and it should be available everywhere in 2012.

Trying to use `shared_ptr` under Apple gets me a slew of undefined references:

```
SecureArray.h:26:12: error: no member named 'shared_ptr' in
      namespace 'std'
using std::shared_ptr;
      ~~~~~^
SecureArray.h:27:12: error: no member named 'tr1' in namespace
      'std'
using std::tr1::shared_ptr;
      ~~~~~^
SecureArray.h:487:5: error: unknown type name 'shared_ptr'
    shared_ptr<SecureVector> m_vector;
```

A typical compiler command is as follows (both GCC and Clang fail):

```
clang++ -g2 -ggdb -O0 -fcatch-undefined-cxx0x-behavior
  -DSAFEINT_DISALLOW_UNSIGNED_NEGATION=1 -pipe -std=c++0x -Wall -Wextra
  -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-tautological-compare 
  -I. -I./esapi -I./deps -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -fpic
  -c src/DummyConfiguration.cpp -o src/DummyConfiguration.o
```

I'm trying to include it as follows (I believe I need to tweak this, but I don't recall the C++ syntax to say "look here, or look there"):

```
#include <memory>
using std::shared_ptr;
using std::tr1::shared_ptr;
```

Apple's man pages are not turning up anything:

```
$ man shared_ptr
No manual entry for shared_ptr
$ man -k shared_ptr
shared_ptr: nothing appropriate
```

I have Mac OS X 10.8 (fully patched), Xcode (fully patched), and Command Line Tools installed.

So how does one use a std::shared_ptr on Apple platforms?

Comment: `apple` doesn't seem like a good tag

Comment: What toolchain versions? That's what's really important. Frankly I couldn't care less about your OS!

Comment: Thanks Lightness. Understood. I don't care much about Apple either.

Comment: Lightness - GCC is 4.2.1 and Clang is 421.11.66 (no BS!).

Comment: BTW please use `@` notification syntax

Comment: @Lightness - "apple doesn't seem like a good tag" - feel free to change it. It does appear to be Apple specific (Linux, Windows, and BSD seem to work as expected).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`#include <tr1/memory>` will work with either compiler using libstdc++. Alternately, with Clang:

```
#include <memory>
using std::shared_ptr;
```

and compile with `c++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ ...`. I have no idea why Clang is using libstdc++ by default; presumably it's for GCC compatibility.

You can't find the man pages because libstdc++ doesn't have man pages. Helpful, isn't it. There's HTML documentation in the source distribution.